# Can't get url from internal uri in twig template file

Tags: theming

I have tried every suggestion I could find and nothing is working. I need to get the actual path or url since I am adding some specific classes to the link. The array is below

[image]

I got to this from the following

```
{% set link = paragraph.field_link.value.0 %}
{{ kint(link) }}
```

I understand that I need to use the url() or path() function but these require 2 parameters and I am unsure where to get these from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to do like this

```
{{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}
```

That should do it.

This is another possible way of diong it

```
{{paragraph.field_link.uri }}
```

Comment: neither one of these options returns the same result as url() or path(), as requested.